# Реализация задачи Страуструпа «Быки и коровы»

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

**Есть такая задачка у Бьёрна Страуструпа, «Быки и коровы».**

Суть её в следующем. компьютер генерирует четыре случайных числа и записывает их в контейнер. Пользователь должен угадать какое число загадал компьютер.

Например, компьютер загадал *1234*, а пользователь ответил *1356*. Первый элемент ответа пользователя совпадает с компьютером и значения *1* находятся на одинаковых позициях, значит ответ «Бык». Если совпадает с загаданным значение *3*, но позиции разные, значит это «Корова».

**Собственно у меня два вопроса:**

1. Что, если компьютер сгенерирует такое число где значения повторяются, к примеру *1232*?

   Тогда ответы будут не верны , так как я сравниваю все значения.
   Я в принципе могу заранее просканировать вектор, найти  эти одинаковые значения и изменить их, но у меня есть сомнения, приемлемо ли это.
2. Как улучшить мой код?

   ```
   // Функция start_game() генирирует случайные числа , записывает их в вектор.
   void start_game(int seed)
   {
       const int v1_size = 4;

       if(seed < 0) seed = -seed; // if -seed = - seed == +seed.
       seed %= 10; // остаток от деления.
       if (seed == 0) return;
       srand(seed); // генирируем случаные числа.
       for (int i = 0; i < v1_size; ++i)
           v1.push_back(rand() % 9 + 1);
   }

   int main()
   {
       try
       {
           int seed, bulls = 0, cows = 0;
           int k = 0;
           cin >> seed;
           start_game(seed);
           for (auto i : v1) cout << i << ends;
           cout << endl;

           for (auto i = 0;i < v1.size() ;++i){
               cout << "enter: ";
               int users;
               while (!(cin >> users))
               {
                   cin.clear();
                   while (cin.get() != '\n');
                   cout << "enter: ";
               }
               v2.push_back(users);
               for (; k < v2.size();k+=1)
               {
                   int a = v2[k];
                   int k_v2 = k;
                   for (int j = 0; j < v1.size(); ++j)
                   {
                       int b = v1[j];
                       int j_v1 = j;
                       if (a == b)
                       {
                           if (k_v2 == j_v1) {
                               ++bulls;
                               cout << setw(15) << "bulls: " << bulls << endl;
                               break;
                           }
                           else
                               ++cows;
                           cout << setw(15) << "cows: " << cows << endl;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: А зачем эти премудрости с `seed`? Просто указывайте текущее время в миллисекундах и при каждом запуске будут случайные числа

Comment: Сранд не потокобезопасный.

Comment: @gil9red я не знаком с такой функцией к сожалению.

Comment: Согласно правилам игры ["Быки и коровы"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B) в числе нет повторяющихся цифр

Comment: Alex Krass но мой код генерирует такие числа , как с ними поступить?

Comment: Я бы пересмотрел генератор и сделал так, что бы он генерировал уникальные цифры. В противном случае Вам придется самому придумать правила игры, как такие ситуации обрабатывать что бы не ввести пользователей в заблуждение.

Comment: @typemoon, у автора один поток, а какие есть варианты?

Comment: Использовать <random> C++

Comment: @Alex Krass Как Вы думаете , если я сгенерирую случайные числа и сразу переберу последовательно все элементы в поисках одинаковых , если найду то один из них изменю на единицу и пульну в игру. Это нормально или плохой стиль?)

Comment: @Alex Krass если я так сделаю то есть вероятность , что другие цифры станут равными)

Comment: А Вы не рассматривали вариант, что будет, если все четыре цифры станут одинаковы?)) Сделайте промежуточную коллекцию со всеми возможными вариантами(1-9), далее берете четыре раза рандомную позицию по длине коллекции и забираете это число из позиции с удалением.

Comment: @Alex Krass Страшно представить если все четыре значения станут равными)) Спасибо за ответ , дальше думаю я справлюсь.

Comment: @Alex Krass Продемонстрируйте пожалуйста свой ответ в коде. Я что то затрудняюсь описать Ваш ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для примера привожу полное решение задачи. В решении не проверяются диапазоны, ввод пользователя, код сделан больше для удобства разбора и так же скорее всего не освобождается память(!) т.к. я подзабыл уже С++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/*функция для генерации неповторяющихся цифр*/
vector<int> initialGameNumbers();

/*функция ввода пользователем цифр*/
vector<int> getUserNumbers();

/*функция проверки количества "быков" и "коров"*/
vector<int> checkBullsAndCows(vector<int> v1, vector<int> v2);

/*печать значений вектора на экран*/
void printVectorInt(vector<int> v);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    vector<int> bullsAndCows;
    vector<int> sequence_four;
    vector<int> sequence_user;

    sequence_four = initialGameNumbers();
    while(true)
    {
        sequence_user = getUserNumbers();

        bullsAndCows = checkBullsAndCows(sequence_four, sequence_user);
        if(bullsAndCows[0] == 4)
            break;

        cout << "быки: " << bullsAndCows[0] << " коровы: " << bullsAndCows[1] << endl << endl; 
    }

    cout << "Загаданная последовательность:" << endl;
    printVectorInt(sequence_four);

    return 0;
}

vector<int> initialGameNumbers()
{
    srand(time(0));

    vector<int> seq; //заводим последовательность требуемых чисел 0..9
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        seq.push_back(i);

    vector<int> ret;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int pos = rand() % seq.size(); //получаем рандомную позицию элемента

        ret.push_back(seq[pos]); //вставляем элемент из позицию pos в конечный массив
        seq.erase(seq.begin() + pos); //удаляем элемент из последовательности, что бы он снова не появился
        /*
            // Визуализация работы, раскомментируйте если надо 
            cout << "шаг " << i << endl;
            printVectorInt(seq);
            cout << endl;
            printVectorInt(ret);
            cout << endl << endl;
        */
    }
    return ret;
}

vector<int> getUserNumbers()
{
    vector<int> ret;

    cout << "Введите четыре цифры используя <enter>:" << endl;
    int n;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cin >> n;
        ret.push_back(n);
    }

    return ret;
}

vector<int> checkBullsAndCows(vector<int> v1, vector<int> v2)
{
    vector<int> ret(2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(v1[i] == v2[j])
            {
                if(i == j)
                    ret[0] += 1;
                else
                    ret[1] += 1;

                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

void printVectorInt(vector<int> v)
{
    vector <int>::iterator cur;
    for(cur = v.begin(); cur < v.end(); cur++)
        cout << *cur << " ";
}
```